# loop through iterations inside mutate

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, dplyr

I am looking for some tidyverse related solution to the following problem:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~group, ~cond1, ~cond2, ~y,
        1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 99, NA,
        1, 1, 1, NA,
        2, 1, 1, 1,
        2, 1, 1, NA,
        2, 1, 1, NA,
) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(y = ifelse(cond1 != 99 &
                      cond2 != 99,
                      nth(y, 1),
                    y)
  )
```

As you can see, I want to update my `y` variable according to the previous values of `cond1` and `cond2` in a given group. In the snippet above, `y`'s new value is given by `nth(y,1)`, how could I adapt this code to make it more general using tidyverse tools preferably?

I would like to add iterations in which after running

```
mutate(y = ifelse(cond1 != 99 &
                  cond2 != 99,
                  nth(y, 1),
                y))
```

I would repeat the process by using `nth(y,2)`, `nth(y,3)` and so on... until some number, let's say 5 (assuming that my real dataset is of course much larger).

Comment: Do you need `map(1:5, ~{df %>%
            group_by(group) %>%
            mutate(y = ifelse(cond1 != 99 & cond2 != 99, nth(y, .x),y))})` ?

Comment: Didnt map result in a list? I need a dataframe. And why the brackets after ~ ?

Comment: Yes, `map` returns a list which we can combine into 1 dataframe if the results are correct. Your expected output is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

If by `nth(y, i)` you mean the `row_number` of elements with non-99 values of `cond1` and `cond2` per each group, you can simply try:

```r
df <- tribble(
    ~group, ~cond1, ~cond2, ~y,
    1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 99, NA,
    1, 1, 1, NA,
    2, 1, 1, 1,
    2, 1, 1, NA,
    2, 1, 1, NA,
) %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(
        new_y = if_else(
            cond1 != 99 & cond2 != 99, (row_number(cond1)), as.integer(y)
            )
        )
```

The result will be:

```r
> df
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   group [2]
  group cond1 cond2     y new_y
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     1     1     1     1     1
2     1     1    99    NA    NA
3     1     1     1    NA     3
4     2     1     1     1     1
5     2     1     1    NA     2
6     2     1     1    NA     3
```

Comment: sorry, I think my case is a bit more general: ```nth(y,i)``` would actually mean the value of y in the i-th row in the group. I am not sure if your example would yield the same results in the real dataset

Comment: I don't get it. you have the `y` value of each row in your dataset. If you don't want `y` of those with `99` in `cond` variables, you may easily drop them using `subset`. In fact, I don't understand your question and the goal of `nth(y,i)`. Please provide a reproducible example and the desired results. You can use `dput` to make a small example data frame from your data. Also, `dplyr::nth(x)` gives the position of `ith` element of x, not the value of any vectors.

Comment: if you type in ```nth(c(1,3,5,7), 3)``` you get 5 as a result: the 3rd element of the vector is 5

Comment: Yes, you are right about `nth(x, n)`. But, you currently have it in your `y` now. Just, some of them are NA. Do you mean the closest (upper rows) non-missing values per group?

Comment: What is the desired y column for your example df? maybe the non-tidyverse expression of your code may clarify it: 
`df$y_new <- 0` and 
`for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    if (df$cond1[i] != 99 & df$cond2[i] != 99) {
        df$y_new[i] <- df$y[i]
    } else {
        df$y_new[i] <- NA
    } 
}` ???

Comment: I am not entirely sure what to expect. I actually think like you in the sense that it seems that looping is not entirely necessary. My question was more regarding the general issue of having to do the same operation in mutate multiple times

Comment: Ok. you may search `purr::map_dbl`.